# Responsive media query work after 1400 resolution browser

Tags: responsive-design

help me to find correct css code that make Responsive media query work after 1400 resolution browser?
Now i try :

```
  @media only screen and(min-width: 1400px) {
     .div {.......;}
  }
```

but this is not working..

Comment: add `and (max-device-width : widthpx)` in your query

Comment: Try adding a space between `and(min-` so that it is `and (min-`

Comment: thank you @JyothiBabuAraja , css code still working below 1400px, i need it working only above 1400px

Comment: @media (min-width: 1400px) { this is work